# How to add a functionality for arabic diacritics in jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, jspdf, diacritics, arabic-support

In my web app, I should create a pdf file with Arabic support. I try to work with the jsPDF library. So far, I achieved to display normal Arabic text like `مرحبا` (without diacritics).

However, the Arabic letters are not combining when the word contains diacritics like `مَرْحَبًا`.

Below is the snippet shows that. How can we achieve that? Thanks in advance!

Update: The screenshot of the problem:
[image]

```js
var doc = new jsPDF()

doc.setFont('trado');

var arabic = 'مرحبا';
var arabic_with_diacritics = 'مَرْحَبًا';

doc.setFontSize(40);

doc.text(arabic, 200, 40, {align: 'right'});
doc.text(arabic_with_diacritics, 200, 80, {align: 'right'});

doc.save('a4.pdf');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.1/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<!-- This file was created by /fontconverter/fontconverter.html in the jsPDF GitHub repo. 
This provides to work with custom fonts (in this case Traditional Arabic Font) with setFont() function (see js) -->
<script src="https://jspdf.netlify.com/trado-normal.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried unicode instead of normal text?

Comment: I've just tried now but the result is same

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Issue Tracker of that lib -> https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/12